# How to create a dictionary from an other dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary where I have a key with more than one value, I want to create a new dictionary with the same key but the value is the length of the previous

I have:

```
dict = {'key1': ['value1'], ['value2'], ['value3'], {'key2': ['value4'], ['value5']}
```

I want:

```
dict_bis = {'key1': '3', 'key2': '2'}
```

Comment: Your syntax for `dict` is wrong, and please avoid naming variables the same as the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a for loop and `dict.items()` to loop over the existing dict, and `len()` to find the length of the values:

```
dict_bis = {}
for key, values in dict.items():
    dict_bis[key] = len(values)
```

Or the same using a dict comprehension:

```
dict_bis = {key: len(values) for key, values in dict.items()}
```

Comment: Hadn't even realized his original `dict`'s syntax is wrong, this answer assumes a proper dictionary with strings as keys and lists as values.